# Most efficient way to look for files in a directory tree that match a regular expression

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am writing a little app that will enable users to specify a regular expression that will specify what files to copy to a location. The expression might look something like this:

```
\w\:\/rootFolderOne\/subFolderTwo/\w+/fileName\d+.mpg
```

So my question is how do I efficiently find all files on a drive that match this pattern?

I have to load the contents of each folder one by one. I could just traverse the directory tree and load every folder in the whole file system and then compare each file's entire path with the regular expression.
This would be very wasteful as loading the contents of rootFolderTwo or even subFolderThree would not provide any valid results.

At the root level how do I know to load rootFolderOne but not rootFolderTwo?

Comment: I think you forgot to specify the language you are using. Please add a tag.

Comment: I suppose `glob()` just wouldn't cut it? You're going to end up with the somewhat unwelcome task of parsing a regex with a regex... Very complicated!

Comment: I didn't add a language as it's really language independent in my option. It's an algorithmic and regex question rather than an implementation question. I'll be implementing in actionscript in an AIR app.

Comment: use the `-regex` option to `find` in a shell script.

Comment: @Barman that would only work if I had the whole path of the file. To get that I have to load the entire tree.

Comment: The efficiency problem you describe would be abated if your application allowed the user to specify the folder names explicitly, rather than including them in the regexp.

Comment: The alternative is to parse the regexp yourself, looking for `/` characters, so you can filter the directories to recurse into. P.S My name is Barmar. Make use of the auto-complete after `@` and you won't misspell names.

Comment: Yes I know but the folder names aren't known. I'll be using this to import files from a digital camera. It creates folders and increments a number in the folder name.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about that! Got it right this time.

Comment: @Roaders, the language tag is *very* important. You get better visibility for your question from ActionScript people. FTFY. As for the regex aspect alone, read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3764814) for additional arguments. BTW, I think I could provide you with a decent answer had you asked this question for a language that can interoperate with a C library. But it wouldn't apply to AS, sorry :(

Comment: *(cont)* ... unless you're ready to [plug in](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html) some C code yourself. I didn't know this is possible in AIR. Ping me if it's doable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient way?  I really don't know in AIR.  Maybe with an [ANE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html) you'd get a better result.   With pure AIR though, this is all I can think of:

(It could be very slow, so using a [worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) thread is highly advised)

```
    private var expression:RegExp;  //to store you regex for the search
    private var matchedFiles:Vector.<File>; //store your matched files

    public function Main() 
    {
        expression = /\btest(er | ing | ed | s)?\b/; //anything with the word test/tester/testing/tests in it

        matchedFiles = new Vector.<File>();
        //scanFolder(new File("file:///C://")); //windows C drive,  replace this with whatever is most approprite for your camera card path.
        scanFolder(File.documentsDirectory); //for testing purposes I'm just going to scan the documents directory

        trace(matchedFiles.length + " files found");
    }

    private function scanFolder(file:File):void {
        if (!file.exists) return; //if the directory doesn't exist, exit this function

        var files:Array = file.getDirectoryListing(); //list of all files in directory
        var f:File;
        for (var i:int = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) { //loop thorugh all files
            f = files[i];
            if (f.isDirectory) {
                scanFolder(f); //if directory, scan it
            }else{
                //if it matches the regex, put it the matched array
                if (expression.test(f.name)) matchedFiles.push(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is the "brute force" method that I have as a fallback if I can't find a more efficient way if doing it.